# Back button on screen with Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I'm trying to add back button on screen with kivy. What I'm looking for is print word in screen and insert back button to return to first screen

What I'm currently doing:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class InputSettings(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InputSettings, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "[b]Insert your email[/b]", markup = True, font_size = "40sp"))
        self.email_input = TextInput(multiline = False)

        self.add_widget(self.email_input)
        self.donebutton = Button(text = "Login", background_color = (0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0))
        self.donebutton.bind(on_press = self._callback)
        self.add_widget(self.donebutton)

    def _callback(self, ev = None):
        if not len(self.email_input.text) > 4:
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.noinput = Label(text = "Please insert more information about your email !")
            self.add_widget(self.noinput)

            # here I want to add back button to return to first screen --> Insert your email

            self.backbotton = Button(text = "Back", background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1))
            self.backbotton.bind(on_press = InputSettings()) # I try (on_press = InputSettings()) but return with error
            self.add_widget(self.backbotton)
            return

## start

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return InputSettings()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

How can I do this?

Comment: With your current code there is only one screen, so there is not other screen to go back to. If you just want to give a warning that more information about the e-mail is needed, then perhaps displaying a popup with that label?

Comment: @ODiogoSilva How can I do it? thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Solved :

Add screen1 function to insert information and set the back button to return to screen1

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class InputSettings(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InputSettings, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.screen1()

    def screen1(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "[b]Insert your email[/b]", markup = True, font_size = "40sp"))
        self.email_input = TextInput(multiline = False)

        self.add_widget(self.email_input)
        self.donebutton = Button(text = "Login", background_color = (0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0))
        self.donebutton.bind(on_press = self._callback)
        self.add_widget(self.donebutton)

    def _callback(self, ev = None):
        if not len(self.email_input.text) > 4:
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.noinput = Label(text = "Please insert more information about your email !")
            self.add_widget(self.noinput)

            self.backbotton = Button(text = "Back", background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1))
            self.backbotton.bind(on_press = self.screen1)
            self.add_widget(self.backbotton)
            return

## start

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return InputSettings()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```